# Why Java AudioEffect not working with Oboe?

Tags: java, android, c++, oboe

**Android version:** 10
**Android device:** OnePlus 6

I have tried to apply Java `AudioEffect` using `sessionID` from `AudioManager` getting help from this [LINK](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/notes/effects.md) but I always get `NullPointerException` when using `AcousticEchoCanceler.create(sessionId)` but when I pass the `sessionId` of Java `AudioRecord getAudioSessionId()` it works.

My Code is:

```
val audioManager: AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
val sessionId = audioManager.generateAudioSessionId()
```

C code is

```
recordingBuilder.setSessionId(static_cast<oboe::SessionId>(sessionId));
oboe::Result recordStreamResult = recordingBuilder.openStream(&recordStream);
```

I have tried this code on **OnePlus 6** and **Motorola One Macro**.

Comment: In your C code what is the type of `sessionId`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you create your recording stream in C++ with `recordingBuilder.setSessionId(SessionId::Allocate)`, then call `recordStream->getSessionId`, then pass that to `AudioEchoCanceller.create`? This should allocate a session Id in C++ rather than in Java/Kt

Comment: Yes, I have checked the sessionID that i created and passed from JAVA to C++ worked alright. I have checked this by logging recordStream->getSessionId and it was same as the JAVA. I have figured out the issue and will post the answer for anybody got stuck

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue of: Why my AcousticEchoCanceler.create(sessionId) returned null even though it was available.

Here is the code

```
  val audioManager: AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
  val sessionId = audioManager.generateAudioSessionId()
  //This is the line that enables AEC, when MODE is set
  audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
```

When mode is explicitly set to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION then AcousticEchoCancelation start working. From here you can enable or disable it.

```
val isAecAvailable = AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable()
val acousticEchoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(sessionId)
acousticEchoCanceler.enabled = true //THIS ENABLED THE AEC

if (acousticEchoCanceler != null)
    Log.e(TAG, "AEC STATUS:  ${acousticEchoCanceler.enabled}")
else
Log.e(TAG, "AEC  IS NULL")
```

Currently, I am using Oboe version: 1.5 stable